# WPF MVVM ComboBox в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

Заранее оговорюсь: код максимально упрощен для решения конкретной проблемы.
Имеем некую сущность "критерий", который можно как-то оценить. Оценка выбирается пользователем из определенного набора.
Критерии выводятся списком, поэтому в качестве элемента управления был выбран `DataGrid`.
Итак, есть класс `Criterion`

```
public class Criterion
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Для вывода этого в `DataGrid` был создан еще один класс `CriterionWithResult`, который включает в себя критерий, и список возможных оценок:

```
public class CriterionWithResult
    {
        public Criterion Criterion { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Results { get; set; }

        public CriterionWithResult(Criterion criterion, ObservableCollection<string> results)
        {
            Criterion = criterion;
            Results = results;
        }
    }
```

Во вьюмодели определяю свойства `SelectedItem` и `SelectedIndex` (они все однотипны) следующим образом:

```
private CriterionWithResult _dgSelectedItem;
public CriterionWithResult DGSelectedItem
{
    get => _dgSelectedItem;
    set
    {
        _dgSelectedItem = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(DGSelectedItem));
    }
}
```

Определены два списка: список класса **критериев** и список класса **критериев со списком возможных оценок**:

```
private ObservableCollection<Criterion> _criterions;
public ObservableCollection<Criterion> Criterions
{
    get => _criterions;
    set
    {
        _criterions = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Criterions));
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<CriterionWithResult> _criterionWithResults = new ObservableCollection<CriterionWithResult>();
public ObservableCollection<CriterionWithResult> CriterionWithResults
{
    get => _criterionWithResults;
    set
    {
        _criterionWithResults = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(CriterionWithResults));
    }
}
```

В конструкторе просто заполняю коллекции данными:

```
public MainVM()
{
    Criterions = new ObservableCollection<Criterion>
    {
        new Criterion
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Test0",
            Description = "Its test0"
        },
        new Criterion
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Test1",
            Description = "Its test1"
        }
    };
    
    foreach(var criterion in Criterions)
        CriterionWithResults.Add(new CriterionWithResult(criterion, new ObservableCollection<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" }));
}
```

После чего вывожу все это во `Veiw`:

```
<DataGrid
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CriterionWithResults}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding DGSelectedItem}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding DGSelectedIndex}"
    CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn
            Width="Auto"
            Header="ID"
            Binding="{Binding Path=Criterion.Id}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn
            Width="*"
            Header="Name"
            Binding="{Binding Path=Criterion.Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn
            Width="*"
            Header="Description"
            Binding="{Binding Path=Criterion.Description}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            Width="*"
            Header="Result">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox
                        Width="auto"
                        Height="25"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Results}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding CBSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding CBSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                  
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Все данные подгружаются корректно, в `ComboBox` есть все значения, но изначально ничего не выбрано (как я только не пытался это сделать).

**Вопрос #1:** как задать начальные значения в `ComboBox`, и как потом достать оттуда выбранные значения? Ведь `SelectedItem` один на всю `View` и `ViewModel` (или я запутался в логике его работы).
**Вопрос #2:** правильная ли вообще архитектура кода для решения задачи такого плана?

Comment: Не вижу смысла привязывать сразу индекс и выделенный объект, достаточно чего-то одного. Ну а отвечая на первый вопрос - `CBSelectedIndex = 1;`?  Если у вас правильно все привязано (если `CriterionWithResult` имеет `CBSelectedIndex` свойство и оно реализует INPC), то этого достаточно. 2. Правильно или нет - каждый решает для себя самостоятельно...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, т.е. я правильно понял, что ```CBSelectedIndex``` нужно объявить как свойство в самом классе ```CriterionWithResult ```?

Comment: Любой контрол, который отображает коллекцию (`ItemsContror`, `ListBox`, `DataGrid` и т.д.), задает внутренним своим объектам `DataContext` на конкретный объект коллекции, а не на общую VM. Условно у вас есть класс `class Test{...}`, есть свойство `public List<Test> Items {get;}`, есть привязка `<ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Items}">...`, вот каждая строчка `ListBox` будет иметь `DataContext = Items[i]`. Если вам такое поведение не подходит, ищите предка через `FindAncestor`, и привязывайтесь через него к глав. VM (`DataContext.SomeProperty`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Нарушает ли первый случай паттерн MVVM?

Comment: Какой такой "первый случай"? Нарушение MVVM - это когда вы используете UI в C# коде, ну а у вас я нарушений не вижу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ "первый случай" - с объявлением ```CBSelectedIndex``` в классе) Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Если это у вас отдельные сущьности, со своим выделением, а не что-то одно, то логично было бы иметь в VM каждого объекта свое свойство отвечающее за выделенный объект. Так что да, нарушений тут нету.

Comment: @Никита Binding ```SelectedItem``` перекрывает SelectedIndex, поэтому он не будет работать пока вы не удалите SelectedItem, И в целом зачем вам в одном месте два свойства выбора item, достаточно одного. И выбранное значение у вас будет храниться в привязанном свойстве  SelectedItem для данного элемента к которому вы привязали это свойство.